# JavaScript Regex: Finding a String that does not contain </p>

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will find a string of HTML tags inside a code editor ([Khan Live Editor](https://github.com/Khan/live-editor)) and give the following error:

`"You can't put <h1.. 2.. 3..> inside <p> elements."`

This is the string I'm trying to match:

```
<p> ... <h1>
```

This the string I don't want to match:

```
<p> ... </p><h1>
```

Instead the expected behavior is that another error message appears in this situation.

**So in English I want a string that; 

 - starts with `<p>` and 

 - ends with `<h1>` but 

 - does not contain `</p>`.**

It's easy enough to make this work if I don't care about the existence of a `</p>`. My expression looks like this, `/<p>.*<h[1-6]>/` and it works fine. But I need to make sure that `</p>` does not come between the `<p>` and `<h1>` tags (or any `<h#>` tag, hence the `<h[1-6]>`).

I've tried a lot of different expressions from some other posts on here:

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

From which I tried: `<p>^((?!<\/p>).)*$</h1>`

[regex string does not contain substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432576/regex-string-does-not-contain-substring)

From which I tried: `/^<p>(?!<\/p>)<h1>$/`

[Regular expression that doesn't contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string)

This link suggested: `aa([^a] | a[^a])aa`

Which doesn't work in my case because I need the specific string "`</p>`" not just the characters of it since there might be other tags between `<p> ... <h1>`.

I'm really stumped here. The regex I've tried seems like it *should* work... Any idea how I would make this work? Maybe I'm implementing the suggestions from other posts wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:**

To answer why I need this done:

The problem is that `<p><h1></h1></p>` is a syntax error since `h1` closes the first `<p>` and there is an unmatched `</p>`. The original syntax error is not informative, but in most cases it is correct; my example being the exception. I'm trying to pass the syntax parser a new message to override the original message if the regex finds this exception.

Comment: Exactly. So the problem is that `<p><h1></h1></p>` is a syntax error since `h1` closes the first `<p>` and there is an unmatched `</p>`. The original syntax error is not informative, but in most cases it is correct; my example being the exception. I'm trying to pass the syntax parser a new message to override the original message if the regex finds this exception.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your regex question, but it is actually correct and fine to have html content that contains an <h1>, <p>, etc before an explicit </p> as, in HTML5 (which has this flow-content rule) the </p> is completely optional. For instance: `<p>Paragraph 1.<p>Paragraph 2.<h2>Heading</h2><p>Paragraph 3.` Is completely valid HTML5 and can be authored as such intentionally.

Comment: Should we assume you don't ever have attributes or whitespace in the tags?

Comment: @AlanMcBee Yes that's true.

Comment: @rgthree The problem is that users are trying this: `<p><h1></h1></p>` Which is not valid because the `</p>` has no matching `<p>`.

Comment: @Teemu It's not worded well, but that's not _actually_ what it says. It says: _"The end tag may be omitted if the <p> element is immediately followed by..."_. The key there is the "<p> element" which means _the entire paragraph_ and not the opening p tag. Essentially, the authored content `<p>Paragraph 2.<h2>Heading</h2>` is valid as the paragraph is intentionally ending at of `Paragraph 2.` when the `<h2>` element intentionally ends the <p> element and starts a new flow content block.

Comment: @DanFletcher I understand why it's desired to catch this and am not arguing that your implementation need to change. Just commenting that `<p><h1></h1></p>` is _not actually_ an HTML5 syntax error, as it will be rendered in the browser correctly (and intentionally) as `<p></p><h1></h1><p></p>`. If you want to be explicit, you will need to catch _all of the elements_ that end a paragraph without the optional </p>. You can find that in the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

Comment: @rgthree Hmm... Looks like you're right. It's really _element_ , not the opening tag.

Comment: HTML correctness aside, the solution is still a little ugly. For example, what about these tests: `test1<p>para<h1>head</h1>para2</p>end` which I think you want to match (as an error), and 
`test2<p>para</p><h1>head</h2><p>para2</p>end` which you would not want to match? Are these possibilities?

Comment: @AlanMcBee Yep that's true. Maybe I should be more specific for what I'm checking for? My first thought was to do that but I was concerned about performance inside the live editor.

Comment: @rgthree ahh I see now - you're definitely right. I think our syntax parser reports a syntax error because it won't validate. You'll get " No p element in scope but a p end tag seen."  at https://validator.w3.org/. The parser is built from SlowParse btw.

Comment: @DanFletcher You said that RegEx is your only option. However, you can cheat your validator and pass a RegEx from an IIFE in argument list, and utilize Niet the Dark Absol's code. Please [check a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hgLgvrb/).

Comment: @Teemu Oh nice! I didn't think of doing that - I guess that work too eh? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regular expression was close, but needed to remove the `^` and `$` characters. If you need to match across newlines, you should use `[/s/S]` instead of `.`.

Here's the final regex: `<p>(?:(?!<\/p>)[\s\S])*<h[1-6]>`

However, having a header tag (`<h1>` - `<h6>`) is perfectly legal inside a paragraph element. They're just considered sibling elements, with the paragraph element ending where the header element begins.

> A **p** element’s end tag may be omitted if the **p** element is immediately followed by an **address**, **article**, **aside**, **blockquote**, **dir**, **div**, **dl**, **fieldset**, **footer**, **form**, **h1**, **h2**, **h3**, **h4**, **h5**, **h6**, **header**, **hr**, **menu**, **nav**, **ol**, **p**, **pre**, **section**, **table**, or **ul** element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an **a** element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This works better than I need it to :) The reason we catch <p><h1></h1></p> btw is because it shouldn't pass a validation and we are trying to teach good practices. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes it's better to break a problem down.

```
var str = "YOUR INPUT HERE";
str = str.substr(str.indexOf("<p>"));
str = str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf("<h1>"));
if( str.indexOf("</p>") > -1) {
    // there is a <p>...</p>...<h1>
}
else {
    // there isn't
}
```

This code doesn't handle the case of "what if there is no `<p>` to begin with" very well, but it does give a basic idea of how to break a problem down into simpler parts, without using regex.

Comment: If it can be done without regex (Without adding too much complexity), then it should be done. +1

Comment: Thank you. In this situation - at least for now - regex is my only option.

Comment: This is actually a viable solution for my problem. As @Teemu pointed out to me, I could pass my validator a IIFE and this would work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Search for `<p>` followed by any number of characters (`[^]` means any character that is not nothing, this allows us to also capture newlines) that are not followed by `</p>` which is eventually followed by `<h[1-6]>`.

```
/<p>(?:[^](?!<\/p>))*<h[1-6]>/gi
```

[RegEx101 Test Case](https://regex101.com/r/eT1mC4/5)

[image]

```js
const strings = [ '<p> ... <h1>', '<p> ... </p><h1>', '<P> Hello <h1>', '<p></p><h1>',
                  '<p><h1>' ];

const regex = /<p>(?:(?!<\/p>)[^])*<h[1-6]>/gi;

const test = input => ({ input, test: regex.test(input), matches: input.match(regex) });

for(let input of strings) console.log(JSON.stringify(test(input)));

// { "input": "<p> ... <h1>",     "test": true,  "matches": ["<p> ... <h1>"]   }
// { "input": "<p> ... </p><h1>", "test": false, "matches": null               }
// { "input": "<P> Hello <h1>",   "test": true,  "matches": ["<P> Hello <h1>"] }
// { "input": "<p></p><h1>",      "test": false, "matches": null               }
// { "input": "<p><h1>",          "test": true,  "matches": ["<p><h1>"]        }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; min-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm reaching the conclusion that using a regular expression to find the error is going to turn your one problem into two problems.

Consequently, I think a better approach is to do a very simplistic form of tree parsing. A "poor-man's HTML parser", if you will.

Use a simple regular expression to simply find all tags in the HTML, and put them into a list in the same order in which they were found. Ignore the text nodes between the tags.

Then, walk through the list in order, keeping a running tally on the tags. Increment the P counter when you get a `<p>` tag, and decrement it when you get a `</p>` tag. Increment the H counter and the H counter when you get to a `<h1>` (etc.) tag, decrement on the closing tag.

If the H counter is > 0 while the P counter is > 0, that's your error.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that. This would definitely work!

Answer (score -2):

I know im not formatting it correctly but I think the logic will work,

(just replace the AND and NOT with the correct symbols):

```
/(<p>.*<h[1-6]>)AND !(<p>.*</p><h[1-6]>)/
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks, but if it was that simple I would have done that. It's not understanding the logic of it that I'm struggling with, it's implementing that logic into a regex.